# Непонятные отступы на странице и между страницами

Tags: html, css

подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего мог возникнуть отступ справа и как от него избавиться? даже упустила момент, когда он появился...
пока пыталась понять, появился и разрыв между страницами...[image: скришнот`]

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.main-image {
  background-image: url(images/pexels-evie-shaffer-2395249.jpg);
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}


.heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: rgb(187, 107, 157);
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.border {
  border: 2px solid rgb(148, 94, 147); 
  border-radius: 00px;
  padding: 70px;
  border-style: dotted;
}

.main-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(148, 94, 147);
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(148, 94, 147);
  box-shadow: 12px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#second-page {
  background-image: url(images/pexels-alena-koval-961402.jpg);
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.second-heading {
  position: absolute;
}

.product-box {
  width: 67%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: auto;
}

.products {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.products img {
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 550px;
}

.overlay {
  width: 60%;
  height: 62%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(244, 115, 224, 0.5), rgb(87, 21, 86));
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 550px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.products:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.product-desc {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 104%;
  top: 150px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: black;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

для отлова "вывалившегося" блока примените временный селектор

```
*{border:1px solid #000;}
```

если лень - можно скрыть нижний скрол добавив **overflow-x: hidden;** для *body, html*

```
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 40px;
 position: relative;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: получилось найти выпавший блок! спасибо вам большое, все вышло)